# Is there an equivalent of jQuery's add() function in Dojo?

Tags: jquery, dojo

Using jQuery I can do something like this:

```
var x = $('#hello');
x = x.add('#bye');
```

This way I have both #hello and #bye elements in the query set called x. Is there a similar function in Dojo?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're looking for `adopt` - http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/NodeList-dom.html

```
var x = dojo.query('#hello');
x = x.adopt('#bye');
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is directly, but the following should work:

```
var x = dojo.query('#hello');
x = x.concat(dojo.query('#bye'));
```

Then x[0] would be #hello. x[1] would be #bye.

Comment: Nevermind. it looks like BBonifield has found a better answer :)